# MATLAB LP formulation of investment problem (in Bertsimas' lecture notes)

Tags: linear-programming, matlab

I wish to write MATLAB codes to solve the following linear programming problem found in Bertsimas' [lecture notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-093j-optimization-methods-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT15_093J_F09_lec01.pdf): [image: Investment problem]

My attempt was as follows (sequence of variables for f' is A, B, C, D, E, Cash1, Cash2, Cash3):

```
f = [0 -1 0 -1.75 -1.4 0 0 -1.06];

A = [1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0;
-0.3 1 -1.1 0 0 -1.06 1 0;
-1 -0.3 0 0 1 0 -1.06 1;
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0];

b = [1;
0;
0;
0.5;
0.5;
0.75];

lb = zeros(8, 1);

linprog(f, A, b, [], [], lb)
```

Is it correct? 
What would be a better solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the formulation is correct the implementation looks fine.
Perhaps it would be more consistent to use an upper bound like you used a lower bound:

```
ub = [0.5000       Inf    0.5000       Inf    0.7500       Inf       Inf       Inf]
```

This allows you to make the matrix A and the vector b smaller, the result is of course the same.